# Ajax client object method invoking with parameter

Tags: ajax, asp.net-ajax

Inside client control I generate a button, with script to run.
I want to call object's Print() method when this button is clicked, the result value must be passed to Print() as well.

How can I do that?

This is my object:

```
Type.registerNamespace("CustomControls");

CustomControls.FirstObj = function(element) {
    CustomControls.FirstObj.initializeBase(this, [element]);

    this._targetControlDelegate === null
    this.markUp = '<div><input type="button" id="theButton" value="Button!" onclick="Foo()"/><script type="text/javascript">function Foo() {return "result";}</script></div>';

}
CustomControls.FirstObj.prototype = {  

    dispose: function() {              
        CustomControls.FirstObj.callBaseMethod(this, 'dispose');
    },

    initialize: function() {

           var div;
           div = document.createElement('div');
           div.name = div.id = "divName";


           div.innerHTML = this.markUp;           
           document.body.appendChild(div);      

           var targetControl = $get("theButton");
//            if (targetControl != null) {
//                if (this._targetControlDelegate === null) {
//                    this._targetControlDelegate = Function.createDelegate(this, this._targetControlHandler);
//                }
//                Sys.UI.DomEvent.addHandler(targetControl, 'click', this._targetControlDelegate);
//            }
        CustomControls.FirstObj.callBaseMethod(this, 'initialize');

    },
//    _targetControlHandler: function(event) {
//         
//       
//    },

    _Print: function(result) {
       //Alert Result
    },


}
CustomControls.FirstObj.registerClass('CustomControls.FirstObj', Sys.UI.Control);
if (typeof (Sys) !== 'undefined') Sys.Application.notifyScriptLoaded();
```

**Update:**
I guess there is no solution for my problem.
 Maybe there is an alternative approach that you can suggest?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by `the result value must be passed to Print()`? Are you referring to the value returned from the `onclick` handler?

Comment: yes, when button is clicked, function Foo() {return "result";} is invoked. I want to pass the the result of this foo to the object.

Comment: The idea behind this is: the object receives markup, any markup, (with some scripts) as input, the result of the script should be returned to the object.

Comment: That's a very convoluted way to do things. We might be able to provide you with a better solution if you can tell us exactly what you want to achieve. Do you only want to dynamically create a button and bind its `click` event to the `_Print` method of the `FirstObj` object that created it? Can `Foo()` be a "normal" function instead of being stored in a string?

Comment: thank you for your reply i will try to clarify: I am devloping a server control, there are couple of html files that act as markups (like that string). I send them to client control via webrespond, and the client object generates this markup (as i did with the string, almost the same). each html has it's own markup and functionality but a common thing: all of them must return "string" output to the calling client object when submit button is clicked. (no postbacks, just clientside)

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to store the `FirstObj` object in a property of the button it just created:

```
initialize: function() {
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    div.name = div.id = "divName";
    div.innerHTML = this.markUp;
    document.body.appendChild(div);

    var targetControl = $get("theButton");
    targetControl.__firstObj = this;

    CustomControls.FirstObj.callBaseMethod(this, 'initialize');
}
```

That would allow you to use that property to refer to the `FirstObj` object inside your markup:

```
CustomControls.FirstObj = function(element) {
    CustomControls.FirstObj.initializeBase(this, [element]);

    this._targetControlDelegate = null;
    this.markUp = '<div><input type="button" id="theButton" value="Button!"'
        + 'onclick="this.__firstObj._Print(Foo());" />'
        + '<script type="text/javascript">function Foo() {return "result";}'
        + '</script></div>';
}
```